# JTAppleCalendar programmatically, cells not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, jtapplecalendar

I am trying to implement JTAppleCalendar programmatically without storyboards, using a xib file for the cell. I have set the delegate and datasource, and implemented the required functions, but the cells are not showing. I can see that the collection view is set up and visible in the Viewcontroller(the blue square in image in link 2), and the configureCalendar() and cellForItemAt() are called, but still no data is shown.

What am I missing?

```
    var calendarView: JTAppleCalendarView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    calendarView = JTAppleCalendarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
    calendarView.register(CalendarCellView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    calendarView.ibCalendarDelegate = self
    calendarView.ibCalendarDataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(calendarView)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: calendarView)
    self.calendarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}

extension TestViewController: JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource {
   func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"

    let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2016 02 01")! // You can use date generated from a formatter
    let endDate = Date()                                // You can also use dates created from this function
    let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate,
                                             endDate: endDate,
                                             numberOfRows: 6, // Only 1, 2, 3, & 6 are allowed
        calendar: Calendar.current,
        generateInDates: .forAllMonths,
        generateOutDates: .tillEndOfGrid,
        firstDayOfWeek: .sunday)
    return parameters
}

func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplay cell: JTAppleCell, forItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}

extension TestViewController: JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate {
  func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {

    let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarCellView
    cell.dayLabel?.text = cellState.text
    print(cellState.text)

    return cell
  }  
}



class CalendarCellView: JTAppleCell {

@IBOutlet var dayLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var taskImage: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    dayLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
  }   
}
```

[screenschot of xib cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkaqw.png)

[screenshot of how the collectionview currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJMMm.jpg)

Comment: add constraints to your collectionview instead of just setting the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Layout

`JTAppleCalendarView`'s super class is `UICollectionView` and it uses `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to layout the items.`JTAppleCalendarView` provides `CellSize` to configure the item size and you also can use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to configure `Min Spacing`.

## Using Custom Cell

I guess you were using xib to Custom Cell, so you have to use `register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` to register the Cell.Finally, don't forget to add constraints for the dayLabel.

## Example

calendarView's Cell Size is 40, width is 280(7 columns) and height is 240(six rows), Min Spacing for cells and lines are 0.[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### here is one possible way of implementing JTAppleCalendar all by code that may prove useful to you :

***Note: It is just the starting point that gets things up and running and further customization is up to you***

**JTAppleCalendar  version : 8.0.3**

**In viewDidLoad:**

```
let cal = JTACMonthView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        cal.backgroundColor = .white
        cal.cellSize = 20
        cal.calendarDelegate = self
        cal.calendarDataSource = self
        cal.register(DateCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "calenderCellID")
        view.addSubview(cal)
        cal.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([cal.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                                     cal.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                                     cal.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
                                     cal.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)])
```

**A custom cell:**

```
class DateCell: JTACDayCell {
    var dateLabel : UILabel = {
        let dateLabel = UILabel()
        dateLabel.text = "sample"
        return dateLabel
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        addSubview(dateLabel)
        dateLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([dateLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                                    dateLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
                                    dateLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15)])
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**Finally datasource and delegate methods:**

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTACDayCell {
        let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: calenderCellID, for: indexPath) as! DateCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text
        return cell
    }
    
    func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView) -> ConfigurationParameters {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
        
        let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2016 02 01")!
        let endDate = Date()
        let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate,
                                                 endDate: endDate,
                                                 numberOfRows: 6, // Only 1, 2, 3, & 6 are allowed
                                                 calendar: Calendar.current,
                                                 generateInDates: .forAllMonths,
                                                 generateOutDates: .tillEndOfGrid,
                                                 firstDayOfWeek: .sunday)
        return parameters
    }
    
    func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, willDisplay cell: JTACDayCell, forItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = cell as! DateCell
        cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text
    }
```

Note: according to [this](https://patchthecode.com/jtapplecalendar-home/calendar-from-scratch/):

> These 2 functions should contain the same code, therefore it is wise
> to have a shared function to reduce code duplication. The only
> difference between these two functions should be the first line of
> code (the dequeuing code).

The Stated functions are :

1. `func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath)`
2. `func calendar(_ calendar: JTACMonthView, willDisplay cell: JTACDayCell, forItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath)`